# Embedding distortion under group quotient

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, metric-spaces

The high level question is as follows:  Suppose some group (here assumed to be a vector space of $\mathbf{F}_2^n$) has a low-distortion embedding into $l_1$.  Under what condition does the quotient of the group by a (normal) subgroup inherit this low-distortion embedding?

Formally:
Let $G$ be a group with a Cayley graph ${\cal G} = Cay(G,S)$ for some generator set $S\subseteq G$, that can be embedded into the hypercube $\mathbf{F}_2^n$ with low-distortion, i.e. there exists $i: G \hookrightarrow \mathbf{F}_2^n$
such that for any $x,y\in V({\cal G})$,
$\frac{1}{c} d_{\cal G}(x,y) \leq \Delta(i(x),i(y))\leq c d_{\cal G}(x,y)$,
where $\Delta(a,b)$ is the Hamming distance between $a,b\in \mathbf{F}_2^n$,
and $d_{\cal G}(x,y)$ is the length of a shortest path connecting $x,y$ in ${\cal G}$.

Suppose now that $N\subseteq G$ is a (normal) subgroup of $G$.
Is there a choice of generators $S_N\subseteq G / N$, for which the quotient group $G/N$ has a low-distortion embedding into $l_1$ as well ?